# Is it impossible to automate testing on the Lightning interface?

Tags: lightning-experience, test-automation

To be more specific, I'm studying a use case where an automation would be preferable instead of just passing it to a user (for QA an acceptance). On the Lightning Experience interface, however, I've hit a quite challenging obstacle: CSS selectors.

I noticed that the default "new case" window, for example, contains some picklist fields which do not have unique IDs to be easily found by the automated tool. A picklist field's div show up like this:

```
<div data-aura-rendered-by="7477:0" class="uiMenu" data-aura-class="uiMenu">
    <div id="7451:0" data-aura-rendered-by="7458:0" class="uiPopupTrigger" data-aura-class="uiPopupTrigger" data-interactive-uid="21">
        <div data-aura-rendered-by="7460:0" id="7460:0">
            <div data-aura-rendered-by="7453:0">
                <a aria-required="false" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-describedby="7444:0-label" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" title="" data-aura-rendered-by="7454:0" href="javascript:void(0);" data-interactive-lib-uid="26">-- None --</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are `id`s, but they are all global ids generated by Salesforce at runtime. It is impossible to use them on the tests since they can change.

It would be awesome if we could get the field's API name in a div attribute, for example.

---

Are there any tips to overcome this issue with automated testing?

Answer (score 2):

As Paul mentioned, you should build UI tests with a library such as Selenium and Webdriver.io. However, an important limitation of these type of tests is that they are tightly coupled with the DOM. If you or Salesforce introduces changes with a new release, you'll have to maintain your tests.

I recommend that you take a look at the [UTAM pilot](https://utam.dev/). This pilot aims to address the difficulty of maintaining UI tests that are tightly coupled with the UI and the DOM in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Use a two step process:

1. Get all the IDs using one of the API methods which matches the element type
2. Filter by the other metadata unique to the element you are targeting

For example:

> If however, you do need to use the ID to locate the element, a different solution is needed. You can capture this ID from the website before you use it in a Selenium command. It can be done like this.

```
String[] checkboxids  = selenium.getAllFields(); // Collect all input IDs on page.

for(String checkboxid:checkboxids) {
    if(checkboxid.contains("addForm")) {
        selenium.click(checkboxid);
    }
}
```

> [image: //*[@id]]

**References**

- [Test Design Considerations — Selenium Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp)
- [Is it possible to locate element by partial id match in Selenium - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium)
- [automated testing - What makes a good selenium locator? - Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator)
- [getAllFields](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getAllFields--)
- [getAllLinks](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getAllLinks--)
- [getAllButtons](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getAllButtons--)
- [Selenese (Selenium IDE) Commands Reference | Katalon Docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-recorder/docs/selenese-selenium-ide-commands-reference.html)

Comment: But how do you get the ID that is generated by the platform on standard pages? Like on a record creation, for example. That's what this question is about. Lightning Components on the other hand are easily tested.

Comment: [//*\[@id\]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJtiF.png) would be the simplest way to do it. Assuming Selenium, you need to account for [async before looping](https://medium.com/@andrey.dobra/web-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-part-3-using-for-loops-6ac711a897b) through the elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited as per David's comment] - You can use open source framework : http://testzeus.com/ to automate the UI tests for Salesforce. As the framework *dynamically generates xpaths* , therefore the maintenance costs are dramatically reduced.
On the other hand, Salesforce has a healthy community for Test Automation trailblazers here : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000DQPdSAO?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC

**Specifically looking for `<input>` with "ids" :**
The  element has no other uniquely defining attributes. Fortunately, Salesforce complies with the latest web accessibility guidelines. WCAG section 1.3.1 on info and relationship mandates that a human readable  element be associated in code to its corresponding  by matching the label’s “for” attribute to the input’s “id” attribute. The element identifier may change each time the page is loaded, but the label text should always be the same.

In this example the “Company Name” text is contained inside a  with attribute for=”940:1376;a” which happens to match the identifier on the  element. A Selenium test can make the connection from label text to input element using a clever XPath: `//input[@id=//label[normalize-space(.)=’Company Name’]/@for].`

This XPath locates any  element on the page with an “id” attribute equal to the “for” attribute of a  displaying “Company Name.” The normalize-space(.) XPath function eliminates the extra whitespace from the text in this example being wrapped inside a  within the  element. It makes the Selenium test look a little more complicated, but it gets the job done.

P.S. - I am affiliated with the TestZeus project.
P.P.S - With every quarterly release from Salesforce, UI scripts might be impacted, so the only other easier way of reducing maintenance effort would be to use a commercial solution such as Provar.